# Computer Science: How are undergrads from liberal arts colleges viewed by PhD admissions?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, computer-science, undergraduate

I am a graduate from a top 30 liberal arts college (according to usnews.com at least) and I've applied to several PhD in Computer Science programs. How do the departments of the, say, top 15-20 programs view applicants from liberal arts colleges? Are they still classified as "top schools"? Or is there any disadvantage in coming from liberal arts schools and not an R1/R2 university?

Answer (score 2):

In general, there should be no issue for any "good" undergraduate institution, as long as the undergraduate degree is appropriate for study in CS. Places get reputations, and recommending professors get a reputation for accurate predictions.

Since this seems to be a US centric question, you don't even need to have majored in CS necessarily, and something like math is probably enough, though some skills (programming, data structures,...) would be helpful. Changing fields within bounds after a bachelors is pretty common.

If you are a CS student in a program accredited by ABET/CSAB engineering board (pretty typical) then you should have no issues at all about the institution, and acceptance will depend on all the other usual factors.

Some top undergrad programs don't bother with accreditation and use other means to demonstrate their quality.

Note that good R1 or even R2 doctoral programs wouldn't be able to run on just the output of other such places, as almost all students graduate from other sorts of institutions. The doctoral program itself recognizes this fact and is designed accordingly. There are good undergraduate programs and good professors in lots of places. You also are likely to get more faculty "attention" at a small place than at an R1. Fewer research opportunities, perhaps, but a typical doctoral program (some exceptions) doesn't start with research.

Comment: Okay, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Opinion only - no data.

I think good grades in a cs major and strong recommendations from faculty who know your work would make your application competitive with similar applications from research oriented schools.

Comment: Is it going to hurt that I have majored in math? (but have taken plenty of classes related to CS, incl. data structures, cryptography, algorithms, computer organization etc).

Comment: No. That's a good cs background. The math will be a plus for any theoretical cs work. Go ahead and apply. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a CS Professor at a US liberal arts college.

Our graduates regularly get accepted in top grad programs in the US.

Most of those who get accepted have at least some research experience in the form of an undergraduate honors thesis. Some have done REUs, and a few have published papers as undergrads.

Comment: Thanks! I have good research experience with two publications. But I am worried because those experiences came in coding theory. In grad school, I signalled my interest to work in a very closely related field (algorithms, complexity, etc.). I am worried that what I did as an undergrad is not entirely in my field. Is that gonna hurt, say, at the top 20 programs? I am just hoping that the faculty in these other areas are able to relate to my research in coding theory, I tried to make it as simplistic as I could in my SoP but there might still be some jargon.

Comment: I think they should be fine understanding it.